# Push Notification with websocket and activemq spring-boot message broker

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, activemq-classic

We are considering implementing push notification system for our UI (implemented on Angular), we are thinking about using websocket to talk with spring-boot message broker configured with activeMQ.

We were able to implement this but we have two tricky parts we did not know to how to implement:

- We don't want messages to be removed from the queue once they are consumed, in our case the user will see list of notifications and if the users clicks in one of them at that time we consider him/her have read the notification and we can remove it from the queue, but as long he did not click on the notification he will still see it every time he/she login to the system.
- I don't want to end up with thousands of queues I need some kind of mechanism to remove all queues have been empty for 1 day.

I appreciate any inputs on theses points.

Thanks,
Omar

Comment: Thanks Hassen, we have tried your solutions below and works perfectly

Comment: great ;) your "push notification system for our UI (implemented on Angular)" is your code or existent library ? i'm interested by this. thanks

Comment: Hi Hassen, that is our implementation for the UI part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > We don't want messages to be removed from the queue once they are
   >       consumed, in our case the user will see list of notifications and if
   >       the users clicks in one of them at that time we consider him/her
   >       have read the notification and we can remove it from the queue, but
   >       as long he did not click on the notification he will still see it
   >       every time he/she login to the system.

one solution is to use a different queue to store the notifications for each user.

create a single consumer on that queue with `ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE` as acknowledgeMode to display them to the user when he connects.

if you use STOMP  http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html#Stomp-ActiveMQExtensionstoSTOMP

stomp command SUBSCRIBE
http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#SUBSCRIBE

> The ack header controls the message acknowledgement mode.
>
> ```
> SUBSCRIBE ack Header
> The valid values for the ack header are auto, client, or **client-individual**. If the header is not set, it defaults to auto.
> ```

when a user click on the notification, you call `ActiveMQMessage.acknowledge();`
or stomp command ACK 
http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#ACK

2. > I don't want to end up with thousands of queues I need some kind of
   >       mechanism to remove all queues have been empty for 1 day.

simply use :
http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html

> Inactive Destination An 'inactive' destination is one that has had no
>   messages pending and no consumers connected for some configured period
>   of time. By default the broker does not check for inactive
>   destinations. This as governed by the default values for the following
>   options: schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="0" and
>   gcInactiveDestinations="false". However, the broker can be configured
>   to purge inactive destinations. To do so requires using specially
>   configured destination policy entries in combination with the broker
>   attribute: schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge > 0.

Example:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000">

  <destinationPolicy>
     <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>
           <policyEntry queue=">" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="30000"/>
        </policyEntries>
     </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>

</broker>
```

> In this example the broker will check for inactive destinations every 10 seconds, as determined by
>   schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000". When a destination purge is
>   triggered the broker will delete any queue that has been empty for
>   longer than inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="30000" milliseconds (default:
>   60000 milliseconds) and for which gcInactiveDestinations="true" is set
>   on its corresponding destination policy entry.